# Right way to design using oop and multiple-inheritance in java

Tags: java, oop, interface, multiple-inheritance

Suppose we have a shop and we sell 3 products. 
We sell candies , baskets and presents.

So a customer can buy :

- **Candies**
- **Baskets**
- **Presents** ( a present is defined as a **basket** full of **candies** plus a decorative ribbon)

I want to achieve this using java inheritance so i've done the following :

```
public class Candies {

    private int weight;

    public Candies(int weight){
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    //setters & getters
}

public class Baskets{

    private String color;
    private int weight;

    public Baskets(String color, int weight){
        this.color = color;
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    //setters & getters
}

public class Present {

    private String ribbon_color;

    //....
}
```

Now the problem is that when the customer wants to buy a present (which contains both candies, baskets and a ribbon) i need a separate class Present that creates a **candy** and a **basket** object. I know that multiple-inheritance is not allowed in java so i am stuck on how could i implement this.

I could define candies and baskets as interfaces and have a Present class that implements both interfaces, but is this the most efficient and right way to do this ?

Comment: *"I want to achieve this using java inheritance..."* Why? This isn't a use case for inheritance. This is a use case for a type property and, possibly, aggregation.

Comment: I don't know if you need separate classes for different kind of products at all (as opposed to having a `class Product` with many attributes that can handle all and is driven by a database of these attributes -- which would allow you to add or modify products without a code update). But if you want to go that way, a `Present` (or maybe a `Basket` ) strikes me as in addition to having its own attributes being a *container* of other products, i.e. having a field that can hold zero or more instances of other products. No need to establish a subclass relationship here.

Comment: In your case Composition should be preferred over inheritance. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create Id in each class Candies, Baskets and Presents.

Then you can create Items includes: Id, cate (Id to save Id of Candies, Baskets, Presents; cate to clarify this item is in Candies, Baskets or Presents).

**Like this:**

```
public class Candies {

    private int Id;
    private int weight;

    public Candies(int Id, int weight) {
        this.Id = Id;
        this.weight = weight;
    }


    //setters & getters
}

public class Baskets{

    private int Id;
    private String color;
    private int weight;

    public Baskets(int Id, String color, int weight) {
        this.Id = Id;
        this.color = color;
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    //setters & getters
}

public class Present {

    private int Id;
    private String ribbon_color;

    public Present(int Id, String ribbon_color) {
        this.Id = Id;
        this.ribbon_color = ribbon_color;
    }

    //setters & getters
}

public class Items {

    private int Id;
    private String cate;

    public Items(int Id, String cate) {
        this.Id = Id;
        this.cate = cate;
    }

    //setters & getters
}
```

Now, you can be shopping with a list of Items.

**Hope it is helpful!**